# Web Development in python with Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have read that there is  version of python in visual studio 2017.

I have read that it contains Django.... since, I think a good debugger, and IDE like visual studio would be great for web development... I wonder if it is possible.. to develop python & Django using Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm is the best IDE for python development I think. You can try it. hope helpful.